# numpy 3d tensor by 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix. I know that **each column has two nonzero values**, so I want to *compress* (remove zeros) using a tensor that is defined as a list of permutation matrices.

I have

```
src = np.array([[2, 9, 0, 2, 4],
                [0, 1, 8, 8, 0],
                [1, 0, 3, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 7]])
```

and I want

```
trg = np.array([[2, 9, 8, 2, 4],
                [1, 1, 3, 8, 7]])
```

which is the same matrix, but without zeros.

I have hardcoded the tensor that selects the nonzero values

```
p = np.array([
    [[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0]],
    [[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],
    [[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]],
    [[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],
    [[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]
])
```

and I can iterate over both `p` and `src` to kinda get `trg`

```
>>> for i in range(len(p)):
>>>    print(p[i] @ src[:,i])

[2 1]
[9 1]
[8 3]
[2 8]
[4 7]
```

How can I do this *the numpy way* (i.e. without loops)? I have tried `tensordot` and transposing my matrices with no luck.

Comment: Can we solve it without using `p`?

Comment: @Divakar of course, `p` was the way I thought about solving it but I don't care that much about `p`. I am looking for some way to encode or decompose `src` and make it smaller. This encoding will be applied to other `src2` with different values but same positioning. That was why I thought of permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owing to the row-major ordering, we can use the transposed version to [`index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) the array with its non-zeros mask and then reshape -

```
out = src.T[src.T!=0].reshape(src.shape[1],-1).T
```

Sample run -

```
In [19]: src
Out[19]: 
array([[2, 9, 0, 2, 4],
       [0, 1, 8, 8, 0],
       [1, 0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 7]])

In [20]: src.T[src.T!=0].reshape(src.shape[1],-1).T
Out[20]: 
array([[2, 9, 8, 2, 4],
       [1, 1, 3, 8, 7]])
```

Comment: Bonus points for working for any number of valid elements per column without having to specify it in the code (as long as every column has the same number of valid elements, of course).

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `np.where`:

```
src[np.where(src.T)[::-1]].reshape(2, -1, order='F')
```

This is what happens:

- `np.where` gives the indices of nonzero elements, using the transpose so they are sorted correctly without further measures,
- invert order with `[::-1]` because due to the transpose, row and column indices are swapped,
- apply [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to obtain the elements,
- and finally, reshape.

Output:

```
array([[2, 9, 8, 2, 4],
       [1, 1, 3, 8, 7]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mask:

```
mask = src != 0
src[mask] #array without the zeroes but 1d
n_cols = src.shape[1]
tgt = src[mask].reshape(-1,n_cols)
```

This method requires reshaping the 1d array back to 2d, I decided to keep the same number of columns but for some case your array might be not "reshapable" to 2d.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
import numpy as np

src = np.array([[2, 9, 0, 2, 4],
                [0, 1, 8, 8, 0],
                [1, 0, 3, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 7]])
# Masked indices of non-zero positions
idx = np.arange(len(src))[:, np.newaxis] * (src != 0)
# Sort to and pick valid indices at the end
idx = np.sort(idx, axis=0)[-2:]
# Get values
trg = src[idx, np.arange(src.shape[1])]
print(trg)
```

Output:

```
[[2 9 8 2 4]
 [1 1 3 8 7]]
```